# Processing XML Validation Output Programmatically in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

The problem I have to solve is the following:

Given an XML file that "almost validates" using an XSD (or ideally NVDL) schema, how can I "fix" the file programmatically?

("Almost validates" means that some elements will have attributes that they are not allowed to have. It is guaranteed that there will be no other validation errors. "Fixing" simply means deleting the offending attribute.)

I tried using Woodstox's validating writer but for some reason it wouldn't accept my XSD as valid (granted, it's quite complicated with multiple imports and abstract types but it is valid).

An alternative is an XML validation library that produces an output I can then parse/process and use to identify the attributes that need to be removed.

Any other approach that produces the same end product is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to "just enforce" the attributes, you can use an XSLT Identity transform to filter the unwanted attrs or add the missing attrs. It is by no means a broad solution to the problem, but a very good fix for the attribute issue.

keep in mind though, the order of the attributes might change after the XSLT transform, since the order of attributes is not a required property of XML.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know in advance what the unwanted attrs are. Or do you mean running a schema-aware XSLT?

Comment: In that case, you can first read the XSD first, collect the required attributes for each element, and then walk the DOM tree fixing each node, or run a SAX processor and check each node as it occurs?

Comment: The XSD is far too complicated, with abstract types and all that. But the schema-aware XSLT might work.

Comment: I have not done much work with Schema aware XSLT, but would you be able to use it when you do not know the XSD apriori?

Answer (score 1):

Parse your XML with an error handler that captures the detected "extra attribute" errors in "remove this attribute" type command objects.

Then it is a matter of implementation if you slip those objects in between a "reading SAX" parser and a "writing using SAX" sink, or if you run them on a DOM tree before rewriting the DOM tree to XML.

The error handler should handle the error, and if you don't intend it to be an error, the error handler shouldn't terminate the parsing.  This will give you fine grain control, only at the cost of writing the code to capture the position of the attribute in the document (and do something with it later).

According to The [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-xml-proc), validity constraints are only "errors" which opens the door for continued processing, provided that your error handler doesn't stop the game.  See section 1.2 for details that indicate this should not be a non-recoverable error, which means that a capture and fix solution should be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to "other approach". I would rather modify the XSD to accept any other attribute: it would be less runtime overhead, not to mention all the plumbing with XSLT.

From the sound of it, you know and somehow understand/are in control of the XSD - you sound confident in saying "guaranteed no other validation erors"... Hence my suggestion.

The issue might be how to modify the XSD if it is "external". If you can elaborate more on how the XSD is sourced for your processing, better suggestions might come along...

Maybe you still end up with XSLT doing the XSD to XSD transformation; it would still be better in a performance driven environment, since you would have to do it once for **all** XMLs, as opposed to once for **each** XML.

Comment: Unfortunately the XSD is beyond my control and is not even known at compile time. I know it would be a lot easier to modify the XSD itself, I would've done it already if I could.

Comment: ... then you should not claim "guaranteed" :).... Obviously then, even a "static" - known "at compile time" - XSLT would not work... You're getting into what I call "a version shield", an automatically generated artifact (XSLT, Java, .NET) that is responsible for XML data cleansing in accordance with an XSD, before reaching the XSD-aware and compliant XML processor.

Comment: I claim it's guaranteed because it is. I can validate the original version of a document, which then goes through a process that adds some attributes (but it adds more than it should). Although this process is out of my control too, I can diff the two versions to prove that it does what it says on the tin. So in a fairly roundabout way, but I can say it is guaranteed.